# QML drops binding after assignment `undefined`

Tags: qt, binding, pyqt, qml

I have a `PyQt5` property with proper `notify`-function:

```
class FriendsWidgetBackend(QObject):
    messageCompanionChanged = pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        QObject.__init__(self, parent)
        self._current_message_companion = None

    @pyqtProperty('QVariant', notify=messageCompanionChanged)
    def message_companion(self):
        return QVariant(self._current_message_companion)

    @message_companion.setter
    def message_companion(self, message_companion):
        self._current_message_companion = message_companion
        self.messageCompanionChanged.emit()
```

Everything works until I'll assign to this variable `undefined` - when it refuses to update variable in qml after emiting `messageCompanionChanged` signal. I've even tried to set a breakpoint - it updates from application start until `undefined` assignment:

```
Item {
    id: rootItem

    property QtObject friendsWidgetBackend

    onVisibleChanged: {
        if (!visible) {
            friendsWidgetBackend.message_companion = undefined
        }
    }
}
```

I'd say after some experience of `C#` that `QML` disconnects binding after such assignment. How can I avoid this behavior?

P.S. My binding example:

```
Column {
    visible: friendsWidgetBackend.message_companion ? true : false
}
```

P.P.S. It does not work even without binding - just tried to connect to a `messageCompanionChanged` signal from QML - it does not update value after emitting.

P.P.P.S. If i change `undefined` to empty js object like `{}` or `({})` binding will work but this is not what I need.

Comment: Have you tried setting it to `null`?

Comment: Yes, absolutely same affect.

Comment: So what type of value does QML report when `message_companion` has been initialized to `None`?

Comment: How can I get type information in QML? By js `typeof` ?

Comment: Yes, I assume QML supports `typeof` (but it might depend on what version you're using) - I suppose you'll just have to give it a try to find out.